# Should the order of template arguments matter when they are all deduced?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

I'm getting a discrepancy between Clang, GCC and MSVC, where GCC and Clang do what I expect:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>

template <typename Indices, typename T, int Rows> //< Bad
//template <typename Indices, int Rows, typename T> //< OK
//template <typename T, int Rows, typename Indices> //< OK
//template <typename T, typename Indices, int Rows> //< Bad
//template <int Rows, typename Indices, typename T> //< Bad
//template <int Rows, typename T, typename Indices> //< Bad
void f(
    const Eigen::Matrix<T, Rows, 1>&,
    const Indices&
) {}


int main() {
    f(Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 1>{}, 1);
}
```

[MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/Wq19rqvPj) won't compile that
but [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/dPKvzqsdc) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/q4EMrEaaG) will.

Is this an MSVC bug? MSVC says:

```
<source>(16): error C2672: 'f': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(9): note: could be 'void f(const Eigen::Matrix<T,Rows,1,0|_Rows==1&&false?Eigen::RowMajor:true&&_Rows!=1?Eigen::ColMajor:Eigen::ColMajor,_Rows,1> &,const Indices &)'
<source>(16): note: 'void f(const Eigen::Matrix<T,Rows,1,0|_Rows==1&&false?Eigen::RowMajor:true&&_Rows!=1?Eigen::ColMajor:Eigen::ColMajor,_Rows,1> &,const Indices &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const Eigen::Matrix<T,Rows,1,0|_Rows==1&&false?Eigen::RowMajor:true&&_Rows!=1?Eigen::ColMajor:Eigen::ColMajor,_Rows,1> &' from 'Eigen::Matrix<double,6,1,0,6,1>'
Compiler returned: 2
```

But if I try other orders of template arguments (as indicated by "OK" and "Bad" comments), it accepts some orders.

Comment: Your code should be fine. From working with MSVC and templates I _feel_ (without being able to back this up) that MSVC has many more bugs or non-conforming behaviour than Clang and GCC

Comment: The latest MSVC accepts all your "bad" constructs - but not when using Eigen. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/dq7KdeMKn)

Comment: The actual `Eigen::Matrix` template is [`template<typename Scalar_, int Rows_, int Cols_, int Options_ = 0, int MaxRows_ = Rows_, int MaxCols_ = Cols_>
class Eigen::Matrix`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html). This seems to be a reason of the issue. https://godbolt.org/z/Pa5nefGv9

Comment: I figured out that the Eigen release included in MSVCs `vcpkg 2023.02.24` (as it says in compiler explorer) is 3.4 and selected that version to test gcc and clang too and they still succeed in compiling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in MSVC. I have filed a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Deriving-arguments-for-template-function/10371321) to Microsoft.

Its was closed as a [duplicate](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10283377) which is expected to be fixed in VS 2022 v17.7 (MSVC 19.36).

Thanks to [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874660/ben) for discovering and to [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) and [273K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6752050/273k) for analyzing it in the comments!

Comment: This bug was closed as a duplicate of another one: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Template-argument-deduction-with-default/10283377 (expected to be fixed in VS 2022 v17.7)